# Existence of Time-Reversed Markov Kernels

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, measure-theory, markov-chains

Suppose I have a probability measure $\pi$ and a Markov kernel $q$ which leaves $\pi$ invariant, in the sense that

\begin{align}
\int_x \pi(dx) q(x \to dy) = \pi(dy)
\end{align}

Then, a (the) *time-reversal* of $q$ is a (the) Markov kernel $r$ such that

\begin{align}
\pi(dx) q(x \to dy) = \pi(dy) r(y \to dx)
\end{align}

as measures on the product space.

My question is: what are some simple/standard conditions on $(\pi, q)$ which ensure that

1. Such an $r$ exists, and
2. It is essentially unique (i.e. up to changes of measure $0$ in a suitable sense).

My understanding is that this problem is equivalent to the existence of regular conditional probabilities for the joint measure

\begin{align}
\mu(dx,dy) = \pi(dx) q(x \to dy).
\end{align}

I can find some statements of theorems which give conditions for when a *general* measure admits regular conditional probabilities; I'd like a simpler (if possible) statement which gives the necessary conditions in terms of $(\pi,q)$.

References are gladly welcomed.

Comment: The conditions for existence of a regular conditional probability are not really about the measure but about whether the state space is not too horrible, as a measurable space.  In particular, it's sufficient that your state space be standard Borel, which covers the vast majority of cases that people care about.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thank you - that's very useful. I'd seen a statement for the existence and was surprised that it depended so weakly on the measure, so wanted to do a sanity check and make sure I wasn't missing anything. So would it be true that if I'm working on a Polish space, and $(x,y)$ is jointly measurable w.r.t. the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, then $r$ should exist?

Comment: Yes - this is true for the so-called Lebesgue (or, standard, or Lebesgue-Rokhlin) measure spaces. A Polish space endowed with a Borel probability measure is classically known to be of this kind. By the way, the right object to consider in this context is not the pair "initial distribution of $x$, transition probabilities $x\to y$", but the joint distribution of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @RW Thanks - that's my question answered then! Do you happen to know references for i) the statement that this holds for Lebesgue-Rokhlin spaces and ii) the statement that [Polish $\cap$ Borel] $\subset$ Lebesgue-Rokhlin? Thanks also for the additional comment - it's all making a lot more sense now.

Comment: The fact that standard Borel spaces admit regular conditional  probabilities can be found in Durrett's *Probability: Theory and Examples*, Theorem 5.1.9 in the fourth edition.  Note that his term "nice" simply means "standard Borel", which means, in effect, "a Polish space with its Borel $\sigma$-algebra".

Comment: "Lebesgue-Rokhlin" simply means, effectively, a Polish space where the $\sigma$-algebra is not only the Borel sets but also all the null sets of some Borel probability measure (and unions of the two); i.e. a completion of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.  Throwing in null sets doesn't cause you any problems as far as regular conditional probabilities are concerned, so there's really no difference between "Lebesgue-Rokhlin" and "standard Borel" in this context.

Comment: I  can recommend unusually well written Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_probability_space

Comment: Thanks both for the references - much appreciated. I'm on holidays at the moment, but when I'm back, I'd be happy summarise the comments above into an answer to my own question and then close this one (unless either of you would prefer to submit an answer, or if there's some other more-suitable protocol). Cheers!